# Rails: ActionView::Template::Error (Operation not permitted Error in production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actionview

Here is what keeps popping up in my production.log

```
Started GET "/" for 173.26.190.110 at 2011-12-08 12:21:24 -0500
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (19.9ms)
Compiled application.js  (9ms)  (pid 4397)
Compiled bootstrap-modal.js  (1ms)  (pid 4397)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 148ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Operation not permitted - /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/tmp/cache/assets/CD3/620/sprockets%2Fa2dc05811f5202de098f49234f831c1c):
    9:     <![endif]-->
    10:
    11:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application.css" %>
    12:         <%= javascript_include_tag      "application.js" %>
    13:
    14:   <script type="text/javascript">
    15:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___536300347_80777950'
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require twitter/bootstrap
```

***Update***

I'm not sure what changed, but it seems to be working now and has been since roughly 1:57 this afternoon. I'm not sure what caused it. Is it possible that caching either inside of nginx or rails would have caused it to hang on and the cache was flushed at that time?

Comment: What's in your application.js file?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to your public directory?

Comment: This is definitely a permission problem. Just in case try:
chmod -R 777 /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/tmp

Comment: This has been resolved as you can see from the update.

Comment: @NoahClark You should submit your update as an answer to this question (and accept the answer) so it gets closed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what changed, but it seems to be working now and has been since roughly 1:57 this afternoon. I'm not sure what caused it. Is it possible that caching either inside of nginx or rails would have caused it to hang on and the cache was flushed at that time?